# WSO2 project and how to start

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I was asked to make a project on one of the tools of WSO2. I am new to this and i dont know how to start. Did anyone made something like this? Do you know how to start? I've already looked for some tutorials or examples in the official web site but it looks like a chaos. Thank you!

Comment: yes, we did something like that.. so - what isthe question? (what do you expect to be answered?)

Comment: Maybe a tool like (Api manager, Data analytics Server...) that you begun with? And how? Or a tutorial that may help me start with these. Anything that can help me understand what is wso2 and why to choose it over other platforms. Thank you for your comment

Comment: What are you expecting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was asked to make a project on one of the tools of WSO2.

If one does not know to which port one is sailing, no wind is favorable.

WSO2 is a company focusing on middleware products.

There are multiple middleware domains suported by multiple products. Some working together, some overlapping from historical reasons. It is up to you to define the use case - what problem do you want to solve, what capability you want to achieve.

https://wso2.com/platform

For marketing and licensing purposes some products are bundled together (e. g. today WSO2 Enterprise Integrator is in fact a set of products esb, bpm and dss)

Where to start? IMHO the simplest implementation is with dataservices, however ESB is the most used products with the most comprehensive documentation and community support

> why to choose it over other platforms

it's always a over choosing a product with feasible capabilities. For wso2 products - they are fully open source, supportable, all built on common core, easy to deploy and configure, with good community support.

As well nothing is perfect, so it's up to you to define criteria and evaluate why to choose it over other platforms